# Pandas DataFrame.to_excel wrong datetime

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, timezone

Given this data

```py
import pandas as pd

dt1 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-11 23:00:00')
dt2 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-12 01:00:00')

ts = pd.date_range(dt1, dt2, freq='15Min', tz='Europe/Vienna')
values = list(range(ts.shape[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=ts)
```

where the resulting `df` looks like

```
                           0
2018-01-11 23:00:00+01:00  0
2018-01-11 23:15:00+01:00  1
2018-01-11 23:30:00+01:00  2
2018-01-11 23:45:00+01:00  3
2018-01-12 00:00:00+01:00  4
2018-01-12 00:15:00+01:00  5
2018-01-12 00:30:00+01:00  6
2018-01-12 00:45:00+01:00  7
2018-01-12 01:00:00+01:00  8
```

doing

```py
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

leads to the following in Excel 2013

```
2018-01-11 22:00:00 0
2018-01-11 22:15:00 1
2018-01-11 22:30:00 2
2018-01-11 22:45:00 3
2018-01-12 23:00:00 4
2018-01-12 23:15:00 5
2018-01-12 23:30:00 6
2018-01-12 23:45:00 7
2018-01-12 00:00:00 8
```

that is, the datetime is displayed as UTC but at midnight local time the day is wrong, i.e. `2018-01-12 23:00:00` when it should be `2018-01-11 23:00:00`. Now with Excel there could be language settings and display options which interfere, but maybe my Pandas usage is wrong already?

OS language is set to be US English and no Excel specific settings. Pandas version is `0.23.0`, Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't support timezones in datetimes. Set the tzinfo in the datetime/time object to None or use the 'remove_timezone'

```
ts = pd.date_range(dt1, dt2, freq='15Min')
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error (with full traceback):

[image]

How did you manage to get something with your code? This is what I used:

```
import pandas as pd

dt1 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-11 23:00:00')
dt2 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-12 01:00:00')

ts = pd.date_range(dt1, dt2, freq='15Min', tz='Europe/Vienna')
values = list(range(ts.shape[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=ts)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
print ("ready")
```

If I remove `, tz='Europe/Vienna'` then it works quite ok:

[image]

And in Python I get the same, using `print (df)`:

[image]

Comment: What is your version of openpyxl? Or is your exception thrown in Pandas? Full tracebacks FTW

Comment: @phaebz - how do I check it?

Comment: import openpyxl; openpyxl.__version__

Comment: It would be also nice if you could provide the full traceback of the exception

Comment: @phaebz - 2.5.3

Comment: Hm, same version over here, let's see the traceback

Comment: @phaebz - added.

Comment: Ah, so you are using the xlsxwriter package, and I was using the openpyxl package which seems to be silent about this issue.

Comment: @phaebz - yup, this is quite the case with me

Comment: @phaebz Note for future readers:  I recently updated my pandas module and started getting this error even though I was using options={'remove_timezone': True}.  I reverted back to pandas==0.24.0, and that resolved the issue.